# SP2013: got error when try to add new word document

Tags: document-library

I am using Sharepoint 2013 Stand. I  have created a subsite and selected a teamsite template. There was OOTB an documents library named "Documents". I went to the document library and click on "Add new document" link. Then I see a popup with this error:

> The Ribbon Tab with id: "Ribbon.Read" has not been made available for
>   this page or does not exist. Use Ribbon.MakeTabAvailable().

What is going wrong?

[image]

[image]

The other way to add a new word document is working:

[image]

Comment: try to create another subsite with the same tempalte and try their? any customization on site?

Comment: No this is a clean team subsite.

Comment: That does not look like the standard "New document" button on a list view. It opens the upload dialogue OOTB

Comment: I realy didnt customize it. The button "+ nieuw document" is just the dutch language pack. I also removed this document library and created a new one. Same error.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the setting for open forms in modal dialog? Advanced settings in the bottom i think.

Comment: The only times i've run into this problem was with a wiki template.. is the wiki feature activated in the site?

Comment: You could as well right click "new document" and copy the url, paste it into a new tab but remove IsDlg=1 from the end of the url. This is to make sure that it won't open in a modal dialog.

Comment: is your master page customised ?

Comment: yes, the masterpage is customised. Is the issue there?

Comment: Check if there is any javascript in master page , where you are trying to open a page in popup . I suspect the ModelDialog is causing the issue .

Answer (score 0):

If the master page is edited you should check on the edited code snippets. Probably should use `Ribbon.MakeTabAvailable()`.

Also check on a similar article [link here](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/ribbon-tab-with-id-has-not-been-made.html)